# searching substring for match in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use my df as a lookup table, and trying to determine if my string contains a value in that df. Simple example

```
str = 'John Smith Business Analyst'
df = pd.read_pickle('job_titles.pickle')
```

The df would be one column with several job titles.

df = accountant, lawyer, CFO, business analyst, etc..

Now, somehow be able to determine that str has a substring: Business Analyst, because that value is contained in my df.

The return result would be the substring = 'Business Analyst'

If the original str was:

str = 'John Smith Business'

Then the return would be empty since no substring matches a string in the df.

I have it working if it is for one word. For example:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('cities.pickle')
df = Calgary, Edmonton, Toronto, etc


str = 'John Smith Business Analyst Calgary AB Canada'
str_list = str.split()

for word in str_list:
    df_location = df[df['name'].str.match(word)]
    if not df_location.empty: 
        break

df_location = Calgary
```

The city will be found in the df, and return that one row. Just not sure how when it is more than one word.

Comment: You need to give example of your data and expected results. At the moment it’s not clear what you want to achieve!

Comment: Hi @PraysonW.Daniel, thanks for the input. I have added a bit more information. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do with the returned value exactly, but here is a way to identify it at least. First, I made a toy dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

titles_df = pd.DataFrame({'title' : ['Business Analyst', 'Data Scientist', 'Plumber', 'Baker', 'Accountant', 'CEO']})

search_name = 'John Smith Business Analyst'

titles_df

              title
0  Business Analyst
1    Data Scientist
2           Plumber
3             Baker
4        Accountant
5               CEO
```

Then, I loop through the values in the `title` column to see if any of them are in the search term:

```
for val in titles_df['title'].values:
    if val in search_name:
        print(val)
```

If you want to do this over all the names in a dataframe column and assign a new column with the title you can do the following:

First, I create a dataframe with some names:

```
names_df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['John Smith Business Analyst', 'Dorothy Roberts CEO', 'Jim Miller Dancer', 'Samuel Adams Accountant']})
```

Then, I loop through the values of names and values of titles and assign the matched titles to a title column in the names dataframe (unmatched ones will have an empty string):

```
names_df['title'] = ''
for name in names_df['name'].values: 
    for title in titles_df['title'].values:
        if title in name:
            names_df['title'][names_df['name'] == name] = title

names_df
                          name             title
0  John Smith Business Analyst  Business Analyst
1          Dorothy Roberts CEO               CEO
2            Jim Miller Dancer                  
3      Samuel Adams Accountant        Accountant
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!